# Getting "net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" error on some AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Recently I've realised that, some adblocker extensions (such as adBlocker plus) block some Ajax calls. I get that error on the console:

```
GET http://localhost/prj/conn.php?q=users/list/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Why does it block some Ajax call but not the others and what causes that? Is there any workaround other than telling user to turn off adblocker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_BLOCKED\_BY\_CLIENT with Google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr)

Comment: I wrote a blog post and video that should shed some light on this issue.
https://love2dev.com/blog/what-the-heck-does-neterr_blocked_by_client-mean-and-how-can-you-fix-it/

Comment: This worked. Right click on AbBlock plugin in Chrome (top right side), and click on "pause on all sites"

Comment: Would be great to have a non assumptive answer.  I'm using no ad blockers but can't seem to find a way to debug this properly.  Why the browser doesn't identify the source of the block is beyond me.

Answer (score 825, accepted):

AdBlockers usually have some rules, i.e. they match the URIs against some type of expression (sometimes they also match the DOM against expressions, not that this matters in this case).

Having rules and expressions that just operate on a tiny bit of text (the URI) is prone to create some false-positives...

Besides instructing your users to disable their extensions (at least on your site) you can also get the extension and test which of the rules/expressions blocked your stuff, provided the extension provides enough details about that. Once you identified the culprit, you can either try to avoid triggering the rule by using different URIs, report the rule as incorrect or overly-broad to the team that created it, or both.
Check the docs for a particular add-on on how to do that.

For example, AdBlock Plus has a *Blockable items* view that shows all blocked items on a page and the rules that triggered the block. And those items also including XHR requests.

[image: Blockable items]

Comment: We had to change the api eventually but we solved it. Thanks a lot for the hint...

Comment: Argh! I just spent 30 minutes or more troubleshooting other things - but this was it! :(

Comment: same here. I kept changing my code and looking for the cause of this problem and it turned out to be my AdBlock was simply blocking the call that I was working on :D

Comment: after half a day of searching why delete and get won't work, found this...it's so funny we are not even mad :))

Comment: You can enable this view in Firefox with Adblock Plus plugin installed by pressing Ctrl + Shift + V. I didn't manage to open it in Chrome, but the filter list by default is the same in both browsers, so it did the trick and helped mi with finding part of url that caused AdBlock to react.

Comment: Was uMatrix for me. Just check your addons.

Comment: So how do you push to production something that will be blocked by AdBlocker?

Comment: Thanks for answer. the /api/adverts/most-recent uri was blocking by adblocker so I changed it to something else and it works.

Comment: For me, I had to disable the Brave browser's shields: https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022973471-What-is-Shields-

Comment: Such a serious issue. This means my app won't load on many people's computers. Even though I don't have any ads there, just the mention of `/img/1.gif` was blocked and the entire site was a white page.

Answer (score 133):

If your URL contains words such as "advert", "ad", "doubleclick", "click", or something similar…

*For example:*

- `GET googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id`
- `static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js`

…Then ad-blocker will block it.

Comment: Great. Im having a **ad**min page ;)

Comment: In my case the problem was having a folder called "ads" with pictures that was shown in the website. I just changed the folder to "publish" and it was solved.

Comment: I have disabled Ad Blocker for page but still getting same error

Comment: In my understanding the ad_status.js gets created when using google products such as embedded youtube videos. So is it even possible to avoid the adBlock when having this file ?

Comment: wait, what , why adblocker block these url?

Comment: This is a major problem indeed. You saved me days of headaches, my app was called ADS and it was in the /ads folder..

Comment: Wonderful, our app is using authentication with Active Directory and can you guess what the url that's being blocked is? "ad/auth"...

Comment: Wrote an article on logical fallacies. Was wondering why my _**ad**-hominem_ images were being blocked...

Comment: I had an issue with the URL including "stats"

Comment: thank you, actually it was Mr adblocker

Comment: was also happening to me in Brave browser for the word 'cookies'

Answer (score 56):

I've discovered that if the filename has `300` in it, AdBlock blocks the page and throws a `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` error.

Comment: I've confirmed this and also notified the team at unsplash.com

Answer (score 39):

I was facing same issue, I was using Brave Browser, disabling protection against site on which I was facing issue worked

[image]

Comment: Brave for me too. I always forget about that thing. It causes weird issues on sites.

Comment: Holy ... Thanks a lot for you answer I was becoming crazy and that's exactly the problem I had ... ‍♂️

Comment: I can't believe it was this simple! This totally solved my problem

Answer (score 23):

Add  [PrivacyBadger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger) to the list of potential causes

Comment: I just had an issue where PrivacyBadger was blocking something.  I think the reason was that the content was on a "test" subdomain.  i.e.  test.example.com    but I'm not sure that was the reason.

Comment: +1 , i've been trying to fix this issue for days and just after seeing this topic, i could find out Privacy Badger was the culprit

Answer (score 19):

I find a case is if your url contains the key word **banner**, it will blocked too.

Answer (score 16):

I had sentry calls failing with this and disabling brave ads shield on Brave browser did solve the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks! I was testing and it didn't work on my phone either. Turns out I use Brave on both...now fixed

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!! I've spent hours on this.

Comment: Additional question would be how to disable this on development?

Answer (score 11):

As it has been [*explained here*](https://love2dev.com/blog/what-the-heck-does-neterr_blocked_by_client-mean-and-how-can-you-fix-it/), beside of [*multiple extensions*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50151073/4058484) that perform ad or script blocking you may aware that this may happen by ***file names*** as below:

> Particularly in **the AdBlock Plus** the character string "**-300x600**" is causing the Failed to Load Resource
> ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT problem.

As shown in the picture, some of the images were blocked because of the '-300x600' pattern in their name, that particular text pattern ***matches an expression list pattern in the AdBlock Plus***.

[image: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT problem]

Answer (score 9):

If there are any ad blockers (Brave browser use default blocker), turn it off. This worked for me

Comment: I use Vivaldi, it was the ad blockers, thanks.

Comment: yeah, ublock origin caused the same error

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it is not the adblocker but Bitdefender anti tracker. Disable it then you all fine.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just switching the order of some URL query params fixed the issue for me (so apparently the uBlock Origin adblocking rules are not very robust).

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a Chrome extension and Firefox add-on by Avira called "Avira Browser Safety". I had problems with version 1.7.4.
In my specific case I wanted to login to a website called [gliffy.com](http://gliffy.com) for making diagrams, but after logging in I got an blank page. If you use F12 (console) in Chrome you can see all these ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT (and other) errors.

Answer (score 2):

This error can also happen if you run chrome in headless mode (for example with Puppeteer or Ferrum) with a white list of URLs and the request doesn't match the list.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers! They led me to a solution:

I cheated this by using a third party server that wrapped my request.
Check it out:
https://codetabs.com/cors-proxy/cors-proxy.html

```
GET "https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=your_blocked_url"
```

Of course, it is better to wrap it with your own server.

Answer (score 0):

Opera Blocker and others check all files/urls in Network. Then compares to [the list](https://easylist.to/easylist/easyprivacy.txt). It is EasyPrivacy and [EasyList](https://easylist.to). If your file/url in [this](https://easylist.to/easylist/easyprivacy.txt), your will be ban. Good luck.

**So... I find [FilterLists](https://filterlists.com/) for all addBlockers!**