# jQuery Error adadvisor.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thanks beforehand for any help provided.
I'm having a jQuery error in my console:

GET http://adadvisor.net/adscores/g.json?sid=9201255328&_callback=jQuery1710697473913198337_1428532714752&_=1428532715595 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

jquery version: 1.7.1

Does anybody know what causes this error and how to fix it? I was looking on Google but I didn't have any luck.

Comment: May be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341765/getting-neterr-blocked-by-client-error-on-some-ajax-calls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341765/getting-neterr-blocked-by-client-error-on-some-ajax-calls

Answer (score 1):

Your browser or one of the browser's plugins is blocking this request. Most likely it is an ad blocking plugin.

Comment: I see, then is not a problem with the site's code but a browser extension or  plugin