# Not understandable URL in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I open a SPA-web application using AngularJS: http://lerna.com.ua/#/

When I open site from google search it open as http://www.lerna.com.ua/#/%23/ in browser url and site stuck loading. I do not understand what is /#/%23/ in URL and how fix it.

Comment: please provide relevant code here. It is not possible to go through all the files mentioned on the link.

Comment: Both urls provided load fine for me. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`%23` is URL encoding. It represents for: `#`

`#` is called Hashbang in AngularJS, it is different from HTML5 mode in the concept of URL routing.

More reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Answer (score 0):

For me when i open up the console it says that it cannot find `advert` module. This is because of adblock plugin and because of his name. Rules indicate that it is some kind of a spam. However i do not have any other problem with the `#` symbol (`%23`).

Read this answer for more info:

[Blocked by client error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341765/getting-neterr-blocked-by-client-error-on-some-ajax-calls)