# Google chart won't load when the site is online

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a little web app that contains a form and a chart (Google Chart) that populates with the information the user writes in the fields of the form. It works just fine when run on the localhost but when I put it online (000webhost, free account) the chart won't show. In fact the whole div that contains the chart is empty.

[this is how it is displayed on the localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDwQL.png)

[this is how it looks online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95PGy.png)

Comment: Do you have a AddBlocker installed? Sometimes that can be the issue. look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341765/getting-neterr-blocked-by-client-error-on-some-ajax-calls).

Comment: Hey. Yes but only on Chrome. I disabled it but in still won't show. I also tried with Edge, IExplorer, Opera and Firefox, which do not have an ad blocker installed, and it still won't show.

Comment: What error is shown in the other browser debuggers? Do you get the same error as this: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT ? You also seem to have a syntax error. Can you show the errors of the localhost in the debugger?

Comment: For Opera: 
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < - error 404.000webhost.com/?:1
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php

In localhost there is no error regarding thois chart.

Comment: Was there any resolution for this? I'm having the exact same issue, charts load fine on localhost, but fail to load when deployed to my website.