# How do I fix the :ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT Error with Youtube Data Api V3 when displaying youtube videos using Iframe on the DOM?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm testing the Youtube Data API V3 to get a list videos by a query term and subsequently play them in an iframe.

I'm getting this error: 
`www-embed-player.js:306 GET https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id?exp=nomnom net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

After some debugging and googling, I discovered that this error is often caused by  adblockers. I've then disabled mine on Chrome and then retested the api call.
I no longer see the original error `:ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` but my videos retrieved do not play. Player message: `An error occurred, please try again later.`

Below is the code. The JS is in the HTML file itself for simplicity.

Any help appreciated!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Youtube API Test </title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: #0F0F0F;
    }

    button.btn.btn-primary {
        background-color: #E12523;
        border-color: #E12523;
    }

    div.jumbotron {
        background-color: #292929;
        color: #B3B3B3;
    }

    hr.my-2 {
        border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    }
</style>

<body>






    <div class="wrapper container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-3">Youtube Api</h1>
            <p class="lead">Let's use the Yotube Api to get videos</p>
            <hr class="my-2">

            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user-query"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-query" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Search Youtube">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="results"></div>






    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        //Get Videos
        $("#submit").on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var queryTerm = $("#user-query").val().trim();

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=" + queryTerm + "&type=video&key=[MY API KEY]",
                method: "GET"
            }).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data.items, (i, item) => {
                    console.log(data.item);
                    const videoId = item.id.videoId;
                    let $iFrameContainer = $(`<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"' ${videoId} '> <\/iframe >`);

                    $("#results").append($iFrameContainer);
                    })
                });
            })

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's about ad blocker. Please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23352822/1327316

Comment: in my case, it isn't. blocker is disabled inside an incognito window. still getting tons of ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT for the embed