# Can AdBlock Errors be prevented when embedding YouTube videos?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-iframe-api, adblock

I am getting a plethora of "**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT**" on embedded YouTube videos. The errors are caused by the AdBlock Chrome extension. Due to the errors the entire page takes seconds to resolve, vs under a second without the AdBlock. This creates a terrible user experience, and most users won't even realize that AdBlock is the cause.

The embedded iframe looks like the following:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXYYYY" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Complicating factors:

- I am not the owner of the videos and cannot control the ad settings
- I do not control the HTML that YouTube generates
- I cannot ask users to disable AdBlock

Is there anything I can do on the developer side to make sure my page loads properly for users with AdBlock enabled?

Note that this question is related to [Getting "net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" error on some AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341765/getting-neterr-blocked-by-client-error-on-some-ajax-calls) but is more specific to embedding iframes that you do not have direct control over

Comment: Instead of using YouTube iframe player directly, which is terribly slow, consider using a library that only displays the thumbnail and loads the player only when clicked. There are several such libraries.