# Safari wont load images

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-400, cross-site

all images work on chrome.
but going to safari, almost none images work.

my website is www.romo-tonder.dk

turning off SSL and turning on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "net::ERR\_BLOCKED\_BY\_CLIENT" error on some AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341765/getting-neterr-blocked-by-client-error-on-some-ajax-calls)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use an adblocker? The ad blocker is probably blocking the page as it recognizes it as an ad page. You can whitelist the pages if you are sure they are not ad blockers. 
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23352822/1684254) goes into detail.

Comment: This is comment and not an answer - especially since you marked the question as a possible duplicate.

Comment: this is a not dublicate