# url.Action not Invoking method in controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple page where i try to load an image from the database.

The method in controller is not responding to the url.Action call.

i have a page in another area which is identical to this page and it is working fine there
(I literally copy the html from the working view to this view and the method is still not invoked).

On the browser is get :

```
GET https://localhost:7260/admin/AdImage/MyAction?path=img%2Fjpg net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Not getting this error in the other working page.

Here is the view calling the controller method:
@model Click2Lock.Models.ForCompListVM

```
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page"; }
<body>
    &nbsp;
   <div class="col-4" >
       <div id="imageDiv">
        <img src= '@Url.Action("MyAction", "AdImage", new{path="img/jpg"})'/> @* NOT RESPONDING *@
        </div>
       <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="forCompList.CompId">Company</label>
             </div>
             <div class="col-8">
                   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.forCompList.CompId, Model.CompList,
                                                new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:forestgreen" onclick="LoadImage()">
                <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> &nbsp; Load Company Image</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    &nbsp;
   
</body>
```

controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("compmanager/AdImage/MyAction")]
        public FileContentResult MyAction()
        {
            byte[] img = new byte[100000];
            ApplicationUser appUser =
           _unitOfWork.ApplicationUser.GetAll().Where(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            if (appUser != null)
            {
                img = _unitOfWork.Company.GetAll().Where(a => a.Id == appUser.CompanyId).
                    Select(a => a.PhotoAd).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            if (img == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return new FileContentResult(img, "img/jpg");
        }
```

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: What is the url that is generated on your `src` ?

Comment: I Updated my question, getting ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: @Kobi If you have some adblocker on then this could cause the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32916582/1807452

Comment: Thanks Rahul, you are right, i disabled it and it is loading now, but the AdBlocker only works on admin area and not other areas, go figure :)