# CSS class is not being applied to HTML image (django)

Tags: html, css, django

I am facing a problem where image that I opened in html file with class included is not getting modified by the class in css file. I checked it in sources tab in chrome, and model class is not being processed. I will attach the code:[image]

Comment: Is your path correct? for model.png, it should be `<img src="/portfolio/templates/images/model.png"/>`

Comment: have you added `{% load static %}` at your top of your template if not then put it. Also your tag should be like this `<img src="{% static 'imgs/model.png' %}" />`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61504793/8601641) at template section.

Comment: Please replace your screenshot with text: template code, settings.py, urls.py, folder structure.