# I have an issue rendering image from database using django

Tags: html, django

``Images are rendering from other pages but nit rendering new page

views.py

```
def hotels(request):
    mhtl = Hotel.objects.all()
    context = {
        'my_rms': mhtl,
    }
    return render(request,'affiliate/hotels.html', context)
```

type here

```
models.py
class Hotel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    price = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    card_img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title`
```

The html page
{% extends  'affiliate/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

```
<h2>Find your next stay</h2>
<h3>HERE</h3>
<h5>--- WIDGET WIDGET WIDGET WIDGET ---</h5><hr>
<!--CARDS-->
        
        {% for m in my_rms %} 
                                    
                           
                <img src="{{ m.card_img }}">
                
                    <h5>{{m.title}}</h5>
                    <p>${{ m.price }}</p>
                  
                     
           
        {% endfor %}  
    
<hr>
```

{% endblock content %}

other datas are rendering except the image and the message from the terminal is:

[28/Mar/2023 10:17:48] "GET /hotels/images/ht7.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2991
Not Found: /hotels/images/ht7.jpg

I am trying to find a way to resolve this please

I tried a for lood to retrieve data from a specific model otherdatas are rendering only image is not.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django not displaying image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848640/django-not-displaying-image)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the server can't find the image at that URL. I can suggest you doing the following:

1. Check if the image file is present in the specified location.
2. Make sure that the file has read permission, and that the web server is able to access it.
   Try accessing the image file directly from the web browser, using the URL specified in the error message. This will help you identify if the issue is with the image file or with the way it is being accessed from the server.
   Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help i tried on the browser  i have this

Comment: “C:\Users\New\Documents\mywebsite\mywebsite\media\hotels\images\ht7_t0Oq6SF.jpg” does not exist

Comment: So it must have been deleted or removed.
You will need to restore the image or update your code to use a different file.

Answer (score 0):

use MEDIA_URL for the image:

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ m.card_img }}">
```